# Animate presence not working in next js for exit animations only?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, framer-motion

I'm trying to set an exit animation to my components in next js but I'm only able to give an initial animation.

Can someone tell me what is going wrong here??

Here is my sample code:

```js
 <AnimatePresence >
        <motion.div key="modalBackground" className={styles['auth-modal-layout']} key="modalBackground" initial="hidden" animate="visible" variants={
                {
                    hidden:{
                        opacity:0
                    },
                    visible:{
                        opacity:1,
                        transition:{
                            duration:.4,
                        }
                    },
                }
            } >
            
            <motion.div key="modalForm" className={styles['auth-modal-form']} initial="hidden" exit="pageExit" animate="visible" exit="hidden"  variants={{
                hidden:{
                    translateY:100,
                    opacity:0
                },
                visible:{
                    translateY:0,
                    opacity:1,
                    transition:{
                        duration:.4
                    }
                },
                pageExit:{
                    opacity:0,
                    transition:{
                        when:"afterChildren",
                        duration:.4
                    }
                }
            }} >
                {modal()}
            </motion.div>
               
        </motion.div>
        </AnimatePresence>
```

Comment: Check my modified answer below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<AnimatePresence>` needs to wrap the component that's being conditionally rendered. It can't be inside it.

You need to either move the `<AnimatePresence>` tag to a higher level or move your conditional logic into the component. Most likely you'd do the former, like so:

```
<AnimatePresence>
    {modalIsVisible && <ModalComponent />}
</AnimatePresence>
```

(In this example `ModalComponent` contains the code you show above).

Otherwise, you'd need to always render the component and pass in a prop to use to conditionally render the children. In your case (a modal window) I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: So do i need to move `Animate Presence` to a more higher level?

Comment: Yes, the tag is indicating that you want to animate the presence of components that are being added or removed from the virtual dom. In your example, nothing inside the tags is being rendered conditionally, so it won't have any effect. Assuming the conditional logic is at a higher level, you'd need to move the `AnimatePresence` tags up to that level.

Comment: This works perfectly!! I moved the `<AnimatePresence />` to a much higher level !, Thank you !

Comment: Is there a way, Animate Presence can work without passing in a condition ?? Like for the unmount of a component once it's scope is over??

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "once its scope is over". It should run the exit animation when it the component unmounts (when it gets removed from the DOM). But if you remove the parent component that contains the AnimatePresence tag then Framer Motion has no opportunity to run the animation. The tag is watching for DOM changes within its children to animate in and out. If you unmount the tag itself it can no longer perform any animations on its children. It goes away immediately, along with its children.

Answer (score 2):

You do it like this, more examples [here](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/):

```
  <AnimatePresence>
     <motion.div
        // initial state opacity
        initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
        //animation of component appearence
        animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
        // how your element will appears f.e(duration in seconds)
        transition={{ delay: 0.5 }}
        // your exit animation
        exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      >
       {your_content_here}
      </motion.div>
  </AnimatePresence>
```

If you are issuing some errors, it's not `nextjs`. Try to find issues inside code/lib of `framer`

Also you are typing inside your div (?ok 2 exit?):

```
initial="hidden" exit="pageExit" animate="visible" exit="hidden"
```

Check [valid motion components](https://www.framer.com/docs/component/). Always try to take examples from docs.

P.S. If you need to move "higher", you just wrap your parent component, or you can wrap code inside your `_app.js`. *But this method means each page will load AnimatePresence code of framer lib.*

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  return (
    <AnimatePresence>
     <Component {...pageProps} />
    </AnimatePresence>
  )
  
}
```

**MODIFICATION:**
I have checked `AnimatePresence` behavior it's not actually doing his work. I have checked how I did the same stuff. Here is an idea of how to do it, the code example is below.

```
//npm install this before: npm i react-intersection-observer
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

//in your hooks part, where you place hooks
const controls = useAnimation();
const [ref, inView] = useInView();
useEffect(() => {
  if (inView) {
     controls.start("visible");
  }
  else {
     controls.start("hidden");
  }
}, [controls, inView]);

//and the component, check how I did it (example)
<motion.div
 style={{marginTop: '1000px', marginBottom: '1000px'}}
 ref={ref}
 animate={controls}
 initial="hidden"
 transition={{ duration: 2 }}
 variants={{
     visible: { opacity: 1, scale: 1 },
     hidden: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 }
 }}

>
   <img src="https://super-monitoring.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/framer.png"></img>
</motion.div>
```

For the many reasons I don't remember, I didn't use AnimationPresence. **The problem** with `AnimationPresence` it doesn't clearly "understands" *where the user is at the moment* on the page. I think it's why they added `isVisible` variable in [framer examples](https://www.framer.com/docs/animate-presence/#unmount-animations). `react-intersection-observer` is working to detect where the user is. So sorry for the confusing info before the modification part.

P.S. Also check [this](https://github.com/framer/motion/issues/289#issuecomment-753875542)

Comment: Your first example is making the same mistake as the OP. You have no conditional logic inside the `AnimatePresence` tags. Nothing is getting added or removed from the render stack, so nothing will animate.